# App Localization for date and file upload

Tags: python, django

I've got an issue with app localization where parts of the forms (picking the date and updating files) are in native language instead of english. I've tried various changing/adding various lines in settings.py

```
    LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

USE_L10N = False
```

I also don't have the middleware line in my settings:

```
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
```